# How to fix continuous reloading of a webpage by tamper monkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey, web-scripting

I'm trying to build a script that will click 3 buttons in succession but after clicking the first button, the script goes into infinite reloading.

The site I'm trying to click buttons on: [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com)
You need to sign-in to see the buttons.
As you can see in the screenshots:

Button 1
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Button 2
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *.jdoodle.com/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

'use strict';

  $ = jQuery;
  $(document).ready(function foo(){

    var node = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    node[8].click(); //clicking button 1

    node = document.querySelector('[title="User\'s Saved Files"]');
    node.click();    //clicking button 2
 }
);
```

Tried approaches:

1.

```
 unsafeWindow.r=0

 if(unsafeWindow.r==0){
    foo = function(){};
    unsafeWindow.r=1;
}
```

Result : `unsafeWindow.r not defined`

2.

```
f = 1;
while(f){
   if(document.querySelector('[title="User\'s Saved Files"]'))
     f=0;
}
```

Result: Infinite reloading.

3. Simply executing without approaches 1 & 2, no button is being clicked on by the script.

Comment: Your script runs on load of the page and then clicks the button which causes the page to redirect. Then onload of the page your script runs and clicks the button which causes the page to redirect. Then onload of the page...

Comment: In other words, maybe it's a good idea check the URL you're on first, then click the button. It depends on the reason why you feel the need to raise the click event on that `<a>` element in the first place

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The click event on the button doesn't redirects to a new webpage but changes the content of the page with javascript so the URL remains same. The `<a>` element is a link to the same page, even if I handle that without click event, I will still have 2 other elements to click on one after another.

Comment: You're not including jQuery in the script header... And if you'll use jQuery, why not go all the way and use it to locate the selectors? Also `node[8]` seems pretty arbitrary, it could change at any moment.